# co-ordinate frame reference frame for head transform (google cardboard)

Tags: google-cardboard

I would like to know the co-ordinate frame of reference the HeadTransform class uses.

As per my limited understanding the headTransform represents the rotation of the head w.r.t the phone. But how are the x,y, and z axes setup?

Holding the phone in landscape mode with the home button to the right,

camera reference: +x to the right, +y up, +z coming towards the face
head reference: +x to the right, +y up, +z going away from the face

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 0):

HeadTransform is a class that allows you to access various orientational data, What you probably want is this:

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/HeadTransform#getQuaternion(float[], int)

(the above requires just a java float[] initalised as float[4])

One very important thing to understand, Is, This isn't movement in 3D space, Persay, It is rotation around a single point, Being your head. So instead of like X meaning moving left or moving right, It means rotating your head left or rotating it right, i.e looking left or right.

As for the frame of reference, It seems to just be some point in front of the screen which it assumes is your head. I hope this helped!